# Adding a transaction in google analytics commerce tracking in 'pending' status

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having a problem when trying to figure out how to add a transaction to Google Analytics tracking in a 'Pending' mode, and changing it to 'Paid' only later, when the customer finishes paying. The problem is I'm charging my customers manually, and adding the transaction after I charge them would insert my details for the purchase: OS, country, site activity etc.. So I need to add the transaction regularly with GA JS, but marking it as paid only later. I haven’t found any mention of this in the GA docs. any ideas?

Cheers,
Dor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Enchanced Ecommerce actions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-actions). You are able there to set 'Pending' state as a Checkout Step. Problem could occur if you want to change transaction mode to 'Paid' by your own. There is possibility to set Transaction ID for a checkout step but I have never tried if it works properly and if it will match further purchase with the same Transaction ID. Try this one

Example based on GA help:

```
<script>
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});

// Add the step number and additional info about the checkout to the action.
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
  'id': 'T123456'
  'step': 4,                       // Let it be your last step
  'option': 'Pending'
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And then, after you manually close the transaction you just need to call:

```
<script>
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});

// Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': 'T12345',
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online',
  'revenue': '37.39',
  'tax': '2.85',
  'shipping': '5.34',
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'    // User added a coupon at checkout.
});

ga('send', 'pageview');    
</script>
```

EDIT:

One more thing. If I understand correct, you will be closing the transaction without user interaction you also need to specify his Client ID (in this case id from GA) to make sure this transaction will match with previous checkout. First you need to save GA id into your CMS along with all the transaction info. To extract if from ga you just need to call (according to GA help)

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Afterwards, if you will be sending the closing purchase action you need to define manually client ID in your GA create call.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'clientId': '35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b' // Stored cid from your CMS
});
```

Having all this you should have now full process of closing the deal tracked within GA.

PS.

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to send the closing purchase hit from your system. To do this you need to take the last step from this example and encode it into single url call using Measurement Protocol. More about it [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en).

Comment: Tomek, could you please elaborate on this: "There is possibility to set Transaction ID for a checkout step" ?

Comment: Checkout step in Enchanced Ecommerce is an _action_, same type of object as purchase. For all actions there is a set of possible data send along (described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-data)). One of the fields is id, which is a transaction id required for purchase or refund action. My point was, to use the same id for checkout (optional) and purchase (required) as it may cause matching of this two. It should be tested because I am not sure how GA will handle this exactly.